# Read from file char by char in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, eof

I'm trying to read from a file from the terminal. The first and the second line of the file consist of the row number and column. While other lines consist of matrix character contents. I was able to read the first and second lines and stores their values and accordingly assign matrix size. But I cant figure out how to read the remaining part.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>

  using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ifstream f;
f.open(argv[1]);

int row, col;


f >> row;
f >> col; 

char matrix[row][col];
char c;
int i = 0, j = 0;


while (!f.eof()) {

    //TODO  
 }

f.close();

return 0;
}
```

EDIT1:
The file contents:

```
11
11
X XXXXXXXXX
X X       X
X XXXXX X X
X     X X X
XXXXX XXX X 
X X  X    X
X X XX X  X
X X     X X
X XXXXXXX X
X         X
XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Read `col` number of chars `row` number of times. Use a loop to do it, check for success after each read and break out of the loop it there's an error. And don't use `eof` as a loop condition, it's [almost always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030925/read-from-file-char-by-char-in-c).

Comment: Do you want to assume that the matrix contains the correct number of elements ( `row` x `col` )? What if it has more? Or fewer?

Comment: yeah, it will contain exact numbers of row and col

Comment: And non-dynamic arrays can't have runtime-determined dimensions (`char matrix[row][col]` compiles because of compiler extension, but it's not legal C++). Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Nice catch. But how should I insert the characters then? And about about the memory allocation of the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    std::string line;

    int row, col;
    in >> row >> col;

    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        if (!line.empty())
            v.push_back(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! But just change argv[0] to argv[1]

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the file contents, so I assume this should work :

```
int i,j;

for( i=0; i < row; ++i)
 for( j=0; j < col; ++j)
   f >> matrix[i][j] ;
```

No need to check end of file, if file has exactly `row*col` characters separated by space

As per your updated pose you need to read white space too
So try this,

```
for( i=0; i < row; i++)
 for( j=0; j < col; j++)
    f >> std::noskipws >> matrix[i][j] ; // Don't skip white-space
```

I haven't tested this but I assume you might have to do some other tweaks (may be increase row to 12).

Also to clear the `noskipws` flag use `f.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);`

Comment: @user2878007 You haven't shown your input file (just described it, badly) What did you expect? Posters here are very good, but they don't have psychic powers.

Comment: @user2878007 FYI..if you're `cout<<matrix[i][j]` for file contents as numerals you will be getting acsii characters of those !

Comment: @user2878007 See [here](http://ideone.com/bWcaQ4) I used `std::cin` instead of file stream `f`.